# User cache data in asp.net web with jquery on next page load

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I use jquery ajax in my asp.net webform to get some data on page load, and then put it on site.
I am wonderring what is the best aproach to persist this data when user click F5 to refresh page. I do not want to do the same time consuming action to build page again.

Is property "cache" in ajax method is the solution? or there is something better. Mayby is some way store data asp.net cache or session, and on postback return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [OutputCache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49704/ASP-NET-Page-Output-Cache).

Answer (score 0):

You need [caching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49704/ASP-NET-Page-Output-Cache). Add this at the top of your webform

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

Comment: If I use OutputCache, Page_Load in code behind occurs one time (allright). Is it possible to do the same with [WebMethod] which is called by jquery ajax? I mean on load [WebMethod] is fired, but on refresh is not.

Comment: I know i can set [WebMethod(CacheDuration=60)], but i would like to do this with attribute VaryByParam. If some parameter changes then call webmethod.